# Ubuntu/Windows 11 Dual Boot Installation Failure: Windows Throws Inaccessible_Boot_Device

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, bootloader, boot-repair

When I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my system, the installation seemed to work normally, but then I tried to open Windows from grub. The Entry was on the grub menu, but when selecting it, Windows instantly blue-screened and threw the above error. I then ran boot-repair but it threw an error. The output from boot-repair can be seen here. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/6S67ttwGWR/. The error that it threw was

`An error occurred during the repair. Error detected in grub_mkconfig. Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com`

The files for my windows installation are still visible, just not the bootloader. Also for reference, the nvme drive is the main drive with all OS on it, sda is an internal sata drive that contains no data currently, and sdb is a usb drive containing the windows ISO. Windows automatic repair could not help. Also bcdedit failed because bootrec /fixboot threw the error of access denied. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you boot Windows from UEFI boot entry? And then is bitlocker on? And is Windows fast start up on?  Grub only boots working Windows. Or no fast startup, chkdsk required or bitlocker. What brand/model system?

Comment: I cannot boot Windows from UEFI either. The grub bootloader and UEFI no longer let me even go to the windows blue screen. I do not have bitlocker on. How do I check if I have chkdsk. Fast startup isn't on. I have a ryzenn 5 3600, asrock b550m-itx motherboard, rtx 3070 FE. Windows 10 Pro @oldfred

Comment: @oldfred, sorry i forgot to mention

Comment: If Windows will not boot directly from UEFI menu, then you need Windows repairs. This is an Ubuntu question & answer site, so Windows is off-topic here. Chkdsk is a Windows repair tool like fsck is for ext4 formats in Linux. After you repair Windows, rerun Boot-Repair report & post that above in question.